# Simple dynamic form

Tags: javascript, forms, dynamic, input, textinput

I have aI need to validate the input by .onblur such that whenever a text input loses focus it gets validated by the same JS function.

My problem is with the JS function. I want to grab the value of the item that loses focus.

```
function valid(){
if (isNaN("this should be the value of the text item??")){

}
```

Thankss..

Comment: Please post some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To grab the value of an item as you blur, you should add the `onBlur` trigger to the DOM element as follows:

```
<input type="text" name="validate_me" onBlur="valid(this);" />
```

That way you have access to the DOM element that triggered the `onBlur` event and can access its properties (such as `value` or `innerHTML` in the case of `textarea` elements.

Your `valid` function can then be something like:

```
function valid(element) {
  if (element.value != '' && isNaN(element.value))
    alert('This field is not valid!');
};
```

Comment: you could use the `document.onLoad` to register a method that would use `document.getElementByTagName('input')` to find all the inputs and then register `onBlur` listeners for each

Answer (score 0):

This javascript should do what you are asking for:

```
(function(){
    var after = function(existing,after) {
        if ( existing == null || typeof existing !== 'function' ) {
            return after;
        }
        else {
            return function() { existing(arguments); after(arguments); }
        }
    }

    var validate = function(input) {
        alert('validating ' + input.name);
    }

    window.onload = after(window.onload, function() {
        var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            if ( inputs[i].type === 'text' ) {
                inputs[i].onblur = after(inputs[i].onblur, function() {
                    validate(this);
                });
            }
        }
    });
}());
```

Clearly you will have to replace the alert in the validate function with your validation logic, but this should do what you ask.

A couple notes, the immediately invoked function is to ensure you don't clobber any globals, and the `after` function is to ensure that if you there is already an attached listener that your new validate listener will be called after the existing one.